# Popup on page load in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <img src="" alt="" />
                <img src="" alt="" />
                <hr/>  
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
```

My site using site load popup in Magento 1.7.0.2. and we close this popup because it is not useful before, but now I can not know how to on it again. When we open home page source code above code show in window. Can anyone help me to find out where this code is saved?